# will or would or must in a sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

*As you all **will** know, election day is next week.*

Can we replace the "will" with "would" or "must"?

Comment: Using 'would' is incorrect, but you could leave it out too: "As you all know ..."

Comment: There's [nothing wrong](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=As+you+would+know&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) with using ***would*** here, regardless of whether or not optional ***all*** is included. Arguably in *some* contexts, ***would*** is somewhat more "hesitant" (and could thus imply "politeness / deference"). And ***must*** is somewhat more "aggressively assertive" (arguably, speaker is implying his audience must be idiots if they don't already know what he's telling them).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, do the following sound correct to you: 1) *A: The phone is ringing. B: That **would** be Tony on the phone.* 2) *It takes just half an hour to reach my dad's office, and he left almost an hour ago. He **would** be there by now.*

Comment: Like I said, using hypothetical / tentative "would" rather than "will" does in fact occur, and I think it's pedantic to claim the usage is "incorrect" in the absence of an explicit ***if-*** clause. But it's not particularly common, and as you can guess from the first comment here, not everyone will approve. I'm not recommending that you *adopt* the usage yourself, simply that you should accept it as "reasonable" if you come across it from speakers / writers who seem otherwise competent.